# How do I install Runway Module on Umbraco?

Tags: umbraco

How do I install Umbraco Runway? I can't find the official runway module when I search at our Umbraco I can only find other people's projects based on Runway. I need a module to create a side menu how would I install runway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Introducing JUNO, as of Umbraco 4.6, the Umbraco Runway is now available in the form of skinnable starter kits:

> **Adios Runway, hello Starter kits**
>
> Two years ago we introduced Runway an easier and faster way to get up
>   and running with Umbraco. Unfortunately it never got the TLC is
>   deserved and ended up being a too complicated compromise between
>   flexibility and ease of use. With JUNO we've have split Runway into
>   four Starter kits with pre-defined functionality that can be added
>   with a single click directly from the installer.

If you didn't install a starter kit via the installer, you can still install a starter kit, see [How to install a Starter Kit?](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/getting-started/installing-umbraco/23887-How-to-install-a-Starter-Kit-) for details.